# android gallery textview horizontal list rounded edges

Tags: android, list, textview, gallery

I'm implementing horizontal scrolling textview list something like an ebook with thumbing pages. I take the Gallery widget dispaying TextViews. The first problem I faced is that the left and right edges of each page look rounded.

Here is the sample code:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:spacing="0px"/>         

</LinearLayout>
```

page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gallery_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

GalleryActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
         gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter(this));
     }

     private class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context; // needed to create the view

        public GalleryAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position; //TODO: get the object on the position
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v;

            if(convertView == null)
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.page, parent, false);
            else
                v = convertView;


            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText("Page" + position);

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Any Idea how to get page edges like on the e.g. titlebar? Maybe another way to achive the goal?

Answer (score 0):

in page.xml instead of givin match_parent give a fxd width for layout and give sm padding for txtview.
And FYI Gallery is deprecated, use view pager instead.
The View pager comes with the compatibility package too:http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

and if u can't give a fxd width then u can only try with padding ,this might sove ur prblm

Comment: As I know the ViewPager comes from V3.0, but I would like to have this function also for earlier versions. Giving the fix width would make the view not flexible. Is it not possible to change layout of Gallery so that it displays the edges plane without rounding?

Comment: I'm new in development of Android apps and it was not aware to me about the compatibility package. Thank you for info, I'll take a look at it.